# Nested ng-repeat by click

Tags: angularjs

I have two append item like parent and child I want to append this by the click event. 
One button is created to append the parent item and each parent item is need to have a child create a button when I click child create it should create only one the child item inside the current parent item.

As of now I know how to single append by click but am not aware of the nested append using ng-repeat in click event so please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Following is my code.

This in View File

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newLocation()">Create newLocation</button>
 <div ng-repeat="loc in location">
  <p>hi this is ne location{{$index}}</p>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newSite()">Create new Site</button>
   <div ng-repeat="site in sites">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-controls"  placeholder="Site Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-controls"  placeholder="Site Name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
    //Create new Location
    $scope.location = [];
    var tempId = 1;
    $scope.newLocation = function () {
        $scope.location.push({ "id": tempId, "Name": "Name" + tempId });
        tempId++;
    }

   //Create new SIte
    $scope.site = [];
    var siteId = 1;
    $scope.newSite = function () {
        $scope.site.push({ "id": siteId, "Name": "Name" + siteId });
        siteId++;

    }
```

As now child is also appending but it's appeding in both parent item. This is the major problem am facing now.

Comment: Add some code snippet or the work you have done for this.

Comment: I have updated my question with code please check it out @AKA

Comment: Location is parent object and sites is child object, you meant to say ??@VivekKannan

Comment: Yes correct @RajathMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a parent-child data structure where `locations` is parent and `sites` is child.

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "Name1",
      "sites": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "Name": "Name1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can create `locations` within their scope and `sites` within its parent location scope. Iterate through `sites` using nested `ng-repeat` within the particular location.

Adding a new site takes the parent location as an argument to push a new site into it.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    locations: []
  };
  var tempId = 1;
  $scope.newLocation = function() {
    $scope.data.locations.push({
      "id": tempId,
      "Name": "Name" + tempId,
      "sites": []
    });
    tempId++;
  }

  var siteId = 1;
  $scope.newSite = function(loc) {
    loc.sites.push({
      "id": siteId,
      "Name": "Name" + siteId
    });
    siteId++;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newLocation()">Create newLocation</button>
  <div ng-repeat="loc in data.locations">
    <p>hi this is ne location {{$index}}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newSite(loc)">Create new Site</button>
    <div ng-repeat="site in loc.sites">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-controls" ng-model="site.Name" placeholder="Site Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: oops! :( I didn't see your answer :(

Answer (score 1):

try this .

```js
 
 angular.module("test",[]).controller("sample",function($scope)
 {
    $scope.location = [];
    var tempId = 1;
    $scope.newLocation = function () {
        $scope.location.push({ "id": tempId, "Name": "Name" + tempId,"sites":[] });
        tempId++;
    }

   //Create new SIte
    $scope.site = [];
    var siteId = 1;
    $scope.newSite = function (loc) {            
        loc.sites.push({ "id": siteId, "Name": "Name" + siteId })
        siteId++;

    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="sample">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newLocation()">Create newLocation</button>
 <div ng-repeat="loc in location">
  <p>hi this is ne location{{$index}}</p>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newSite(loc)">Create new Site</button>
   <div ng-repeat="site in loc.sites">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-controls"  placeholder="Site Name" ng-model="site.Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" ng-model="site.id" class="form-controls"  placeholder="Site Name"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you also for your effort :)